# Replace first word in a string within query

Tags: sql, replace, substring, sql-server-2016

running SQL sever 2016

say i have values like

| Type |
| --- |
| Coat 2 |
| Furry Coat 1 |
| Coat 2 |
| Furry Coat 3 |
| Coat 5 |
| Furry Coat 1 |
| Coat 3 |
| Furry Coat 3 |

i want to replace all the strings that say "Coat" to "Skinny Coat" within my query but i dont want to include the "Furry Coat" values.
how do i do this?
i tried using the

```
replace(Type, 'Coat', 'Skinny Coat') as Type
```

but it changes all strings

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CASE` logic along with `LIKE` here:

```sql
SELECT Type,
       CASE WHEN Type NOT LIKE 'Furry Coat%'
            THEN REPLACE(Type, 'Coat', 'Skinny Coat') ELSE Type END AS NEW_TYPE
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You Exclude `'Furry Coat'`

```
SELECT  REPLACE(Type, 'Coat', 'Skinny Coat') as Type
FROM TABLE
WHERE TYPE NOT IN ('WHAT','YOU','WANT','TO','EXCLUDE);
```

Comment: hi, sorry  i still want the other strings to come out in my output so i cant exclude them in my where clause